# How to prevent validation until the user enters data into a field?

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm

I have WPF form with regular controls: combobox, TextEdit etc.

I am using standard WPF validation:

1. ViewModel mandatory properties have required attribute w/ message
2. ViewModel implements IDataErrorInfo
3. Mandatory Control has ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True in binding

When form is shown with new ViewModel mandatory controls are adorned w/ Error template.
To me it seems that it is how WPF validation suppose and designed to work.

Other people on my team argue (respectfully) that it is not acceptable practice to show user validation errors before user entered any data.

Which makes sense to me. So if I want to show validation error only after user entered data I need somehow suspend validation until user enters data and then trigger validation.
To me it seems like reinventing a wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a *really* simple way to 'ignore' the validation of the `IDataErrorInfo` interface. Now different developers will implement their validation in different ways, but at some stage and in some location, we will all have some `if ... else` statements. This solution will require you to add a `bool` property to your data type class(es), or preferably a base class for your data types, if you have one:

```
public bool IsValidatable { get; set; } // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged here
```

Of course, you'll need to notify the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event of changes to this property, so please don't follow my lazy example above. Now, you may well have guessed the rest of the solution... it just involves an additional `if` statement wherever you have defined your validation conditons:

```
public override string this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        string error = string.Empty;
        if (IsValidatable)
        { 
            if (propertyName == "Name" && Name.IsNullOrEmpty()) error = "You must enter the Name field.";
            else if (propertyName == "Name" && !Name.ValidateMaximumLength(127)) error = propertyName.GetMaximumLengthError(127);
            ...
            else if (propertyName == "Description" && !Description.ValidateMaximumLength(512)) error = propertyName.GetMaximumLengthError(512);
        }
        return error;
    }
}
```

Finally, to make your data type validatable, simply do this from your view model:

```
dataType.IsValidatable = true;
```

To stop validation, simply do this from your view model:

```
dataType.IsValidatable = false;
```

This is easily extendable... if you have defined a custom collection for your data types, you can simply iterate through each collection item and set the `IsValidatable` property to the input value:

```
collection.IsValidatable = true;
```

Comment: That's what my colleague suggested. To me it seems odd that WPF does not have built in mechanism. but more general question is What is accepted paradigm?

Comment: You should have listened to them. It is frustrating when .NET classes don't provide certain functionality, but it's always best to accept it and move on. This *should* have been built into the `IDataErrorInfo` interface (along with the ability to handle multiple simultaneous errors) but it wasn't. Luckily the situation can be easily remedied by simply adding a `bool` property. As for the *accepted paradigm*... accepted by whom? Does it really matter if other people also use this same technique or not? For me personally, this has always worked a treat.

Comment: By accepted paradigm I meant that User sees validation errors before he entered anything. As for solutions I care a) it works and b)how good it is. so yours is definitely elegant one.

Comment: Well that is a strange use for that term, but with this system, when you are not validating (`dataType.IsValidatable = false`), there will be no validation errors. When you are validating, there *could* be validation errors, obviously depending on user input.