# Run validation when a user input something in a text field

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, telerik, radwindow

What do I need to do, if I want the validation run when a user input something in a text field, not when the window pop up. Here is the example image: [image: Product Window Textboxes]

In the example image when I executed this window, it validates automatically. I want it to check the validation when I input something.

Here is my code snippet in validation:

```
public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = string.Empty;
                switch (propertyName)
                {
                    case "Name":
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name))
                            error = "Name is required!";
                        break;
                    case "Url":
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url))
                            error = "Url is required!";
                        else if (!Regex.IsMatch(Url, @"(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[\w]+\.)([a-zA-Z\.]{2,6})([\/\w\.-]*)*\/?"))
                            error = "Url is invalid";
                        break;
                    case "Price":
                        if (Price < 0)
                            error = "Price cannot be negative!";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            return error;
        }
    }
```

Here is the code snippet in my UI:

```
 <!--Product Name-->
    <Label Content="Name:" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtName" 
             Grid.Column="2"
             Validation.Error="ValidationError"
             Text="{Binding Name, 
                    Mode=TwoWay, 
                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                    NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <!--Product Url-->
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Content="Url:" />
    <TextBox x:Name="txtUrl" 
             Grid.Row="2" 
             Grid.Column="2"
             Validation.Error="ValidationError"
             Text="{Binding Url, 
                    Mode=TwoWay, 
                    ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                    NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "when I input something" you mean "everytime I press a key", then change your Binding `UpdateSourceTrigger` value to `PropertyChanged` on the TextBox. This will mean that whenever the TextBox's value is changed, it will automatically update the bound object and trigger the `IDataErrorInfo` interface calls to update the status of the `TextBox`.

**Update:**

You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface to allow `IDataErrorInfo` to function correctly.

```
public class MyObject : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{

 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

 private string _myValue;
 public string MyValue
 {
   get { return _myValue; }
   set 
   {
     _myValue = value;
     OnPropertyChanged("MyValue");
   }
 }

 private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
 {
     var handler = PropertyChanged;
     if (handler != null)
     PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
 }

 public string Error
    {
        get { return null; }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            string returnValue = null;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                case "MyValue":
                   if MyValue != "expected"
                      returnValue = "MyValue is not expected";
            }
            return returnValue;
         }
    }

}
```

**Note:** `IDataErrorInfo` is only called when `MyValue` is retrieved after update notification to the UI (thus the `get` implementation instead of `set` in the indexer)

Comment: Could you add the declaration of the Url property to the code snippets please?

Comment: it's `public string url {get; set;}`

Comment: There's your issue. You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel object. When you call the `set` you need to raise the `PropertyChangedEvent` to notify the whole `Binding` subsystem that something has happened.

Comment: could you give me an example?

Comment: Updated with example and explanation.

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged("MyValue");` error on this statement

Comment: Updated example - missed the change in parameter type.

Comment: when I used `string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name)` then `error = "Name is required"` validation runs automatically when executing a window with input fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use the [`IDataErrorInfo` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate your data objects for two main reasons... firstly, it is more versatile than using `ValidationRules` and secondly because it just makes more sense to have your data validation code in your models with your data properties.

Moving on, there is a property in the `Binding` class named `UpdateSourceTrigger` that *Gets or sets a value that determines the timing of binding source updates.* See the [`Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for full information, but in basic this property affects when the property changes are passed to the `Binding` source.

If you set this property to `UpdateSourceTrigger.LostFocus`, then it will only update the `Binding` values when the current control loses focus, eg. when the user tabs to another control. There is also another value of `UpdateSourceTrigger.Explicit`, which you may prefer, as this effectively holds off property changes until you manually call the [`BindingExpression.UpdateSource` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingexpression.updatesource(v=vs.110).aspx).

Now I *could* be mistaken here, but as far as I'm aware, if there are no property changes, then there are no validation checks (when using the `IDataErrorInfo` interface).

Finally, if none of that works, please see my answer to the [How to prevent validation until the user enters data into a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564244/how-to-prevent-validation-until-the-user-enters-data-into-a-field/23564922#23564922) question.

Comment: I'm using IDataErrorInfo, actually I'm using a library that I downloaded here: [link](https://mvvmvalidation.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I check your answer to the link that you gave, would explain the use of `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` in details. I'm still new in C# programming, still lack of knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: I changed my code, since there is a lot to declare when using a library in validation than using just the `IDataErrorInfo`.

Comment: It is the event that is used by the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) to pass the name of the property that just changed. It is responsible for enabling two way data binding between the UI and the data source.

Comment: I see. but how can I use it when wanting not to fire up the validation in window execution?

Comment: As I said in my answer, set the `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` to anything apart from `PropertyChanged` which would update the `Binding`s immediately... no property changes should mean no validation should occur. Just jump in and give it a go... try in a new small project if you're not sure.

Comment: still don't get setting `INotifyPropertyChanged` to `public bool IsValidatable`

Comment: There is an `IsValidatable` condition that encapsulates the code that validates the data object, so if it is set to `false`, then the data object won't be validated... but that's more about the `IDataErrorInfo` interface than the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.