# WPF TextBox: prevent validation rule to fire until user edition

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox

In order to control user input on a WPF TextBox I have bound a validation rule to it. Validation rule works perfectly. It validates if TextBox is empty among other things.

But there is a thing I don't like: when window (xaml view) is open for first time, the TextBox marked as invalid (red border around) since this TextBox is empty by default at the beginning.

This TextBox is automatically populated later when user performs some actions on an WPF Listbox in the same window.

So I would like the empty TextBox not being marked as invalid with red border around for first time when window is loaded.

I don't know if there is a way to stop validation rule from being fired for first time and enable it later. If so how?

How can I achieve this?

Comment: This may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564244/how-to-prevent-validation-until-the-user-enters-data-into-a-field

Comment: @Ramji A lot of thanks for the link. It is very helpful. Also I found another one that basically does the same through a boolean property: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1503033/1624552

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know if there is a way to stop validation rule from being fired for first time and enable it later. If so how?

Set the `ValidatesOnTargetUpdated` property of the `ValidationRule` to `false`, or don't set it all since `false` is the default value.

Comment: and then how do I activate it? from view model?

Comment: ValidationRules are not used in a view model. If you use MVVM, you should implement `INotifyDataErrorInfo` in your view models instead of using validation rules in the view.

Comment: In the view, it "activates" itself.

Comment: @Ralph: Please remember to accept the answer if your original issue has been solved.